# Creating an entire doubly linked list in one function

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, scanf

I'm new to DSA and currently learning linked-list. I was trying to create an entire linked list in one function. The first scanf in createList function doesn't seem to assign the input to the address provided(i.e. &n). I tried printing n right after scanf. It doesn't print n to console at all.
As a result, the output is not the way I expected. I can't figure out why.

//ENTIRE CODE HERE

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node {
    struct node* prev;
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};

void print_nodes(struct node* );
struct node* addToEmpty(struct node*, int);
struct node* addAtEnd(struct node*, int);
struct node* createList(struct node*);

int main() {
    struct node* head = NULL;
    head = createList(head);
    print_nodes(head);
}

void print_nodes(struct node* head) {
    struct node* ptr = head;
    while (ptr != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", ptr->data);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

struct node* addToEmpty(struct node* head, int data) {
    struct node* temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->prev = NULL;
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = NULL;
    head = temp;
    return head;
}

struct node* addAtEnd(struct node* head, int data) {
    struct node* tp = head;
    struct node* temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->prev = NULL;
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = NULL;
    while (tp->next != NULL) {
        tp = tp->next;
    }
    tp->next = temp;
    temp->prev = tp;
    return head;
}

struct node* createList(struct node* head) {
    int n, data, i;
    printf("Enter the number of nodes: ");
    scanf("%d ", &n);

    if (n == 0)
        return head;

    printf("Enter the element of node 1: ");
    scanf("%d ", &data);
    head = addToEmpty(head, data);

    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        printf("Enter the element of node %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &data);
        head = addAtEnd(head, data);
    }
    return head;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is so simple , instead of `scanf("%d ", &n);` , just write `scanf("%d", &n);` by which I mean to remove the wite space after `%d` as it's producing some strange behavior in your case , as if you refer to [scanf() manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) , they say that :

> A sequence of white-space characters (space, tab, newline,
> etc.; see isspace(3)).  This directive matches any amount
> of white space, including none, in the input.

which is supposed to ignore any whitespace after the number entered till getting a valid char.

and here is the full code but with this only small modification:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node {
    struct node* prev;
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};

void print_nodes(struct node* );
struct node* addToEmpty(struct node*, int);
struct node* addAtEnd(struct node*, int);
struct node* createList(struct node*);

int main() {
    struct node* head = NULL;
    head = createList(head);
    print_nodes(head);
}

void print_nodes(struct node* head) {
    struct node* ptr = head;
    while (ptr != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", ptr->data);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

struct node* addToEmpty(struct node* head, int data) {
    struct node* temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->prev = NULL;
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = NULL;
    head = temp;
    return head;
}

struct node* addAtEnd(struct node* head, int data) {
    struct node* tp = head;
    struct node* temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->prev = NULL;
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = NULL;
    while (tp->next != NULL) {
        tp = tp->next;
    }
    tp->next = temp;
    temp->prev = tp;
    return head;
}

struct node* createList(struct node* head) {
    int n, data, i;
    printf("Enter the number of nodes: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    if (n == 0)
        return head;

    printf("Enter the element of node 1: ");
    scanf("%d", &data);
    head = addToEmpty(head, data);

    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        printf("Enter the element of node %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &data);
        head = addAtEnd(head, data);
    }
    return head;
}
```

and this is the output:

```
 Enter the number of nodes:3
 Enter the element of node 1:1
 Enter the element of node 2:2
 Enter the element of node 3:3
 1 2 3
```

Comment: Damn. I never knew about this.

Answer (score 0):

I tried out your code and found issues with the space in the literal string in the "scanf" statements.  I see that someone else found that and offered up the solution to that with the cleanup of the "scanf" statements.  I would say that if you are to accept an answer, select the first one.  However, I just wanted to also offer up my code snippet with a couple of additional tweaks.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node
{
    struct node* prev;
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};

void print_nodes(struct node* );
struct node* addToEmpty(struct node*, int);
void addAtEnd(struct node*, int);           /* No requirement for a node to be returned as the pointers are all set up in the function */
struct node* createList(struct node*);

int main()
{
    struct node* head = NULL;
    head = createList(head);
    print_nodes(head);
}

void print_nodes(struct node* head)
{
    struct node* ptr = head;
    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", ptr->data);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

struct node* addToEmpty(struct node* head, int data)
{
    struct node* temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->prev = NULL;
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = NULL;
    //head = temp;
    return temp;        /* Return the pointer to the new struct - no need for update of head here */
}

void addAtEnd(struct node* head, int data)
{
    struct node* tp = head;
    struct node* temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->prev = NULL;
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = NULL;
    while (tp->next != NULL)
    {
        tp = tp->next;
    }
    tp->next = temp;
    temp->prev = tp;
    return;
}

struct node* createList(struct node* head)
{
    int n, data, i;
    printf("Enter the number of nodes: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    if (n == 0)
        return head;

    printf("Enter the element of node 1: ");
    scanf("%d", &data);
    head = addToEmpty(head, data);

    for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the element of node %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &data);
        addAtEnd(head, data);
    }
    return head;
}
```

First off, since there is not a need to return a "struct" pointer in the function "addAtEnd", I revised that to be a "void" function return signature.  Second, in the "addToEmpty" function, one can just return the pointer value in "temp" instead of placing the value into the input parameter "head"; however, it works either way.  It is just a matter of choice.

As a sample, here is some output data at the terminal.

```
@Una:~/C_Programs/Console/CompleteList/bin/Release$ ./CompleteList 
Enter the number of nodes: 4
Enter the element of node 1: 65535
Enter the element of node 2: 2458
Enter the element of node 3: -44
Enter the element of node 4: 3258779
65535 2458 -44 3258779
```

I would suggest trying out both iterations.

Comment: This is very helpful as well. Since the "addAtEnd" function does not update the "head" pointer, the function can be made "void".

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have pointed at the specific problem you experienced (bad `scanf()` parameter string).

Going beyond that, however, there are two other "issues(?)".

First is to "create an entire linked list in **one** function".
In your code, `main()` calls only one function, but that function uses two "helper" functions to get the job done.
Every line of code is an opportunity for a ***bug*** to lurk unseen.
Re-using code is a way to reduce the chances for *bugs* to appear.

Secondly, the code appears to be correct, but does not *prove* that the doubly linked list is anything more than a singly linked list.

Both of these matters are addressed below creating (in **one** function, and later demonstrating) a **circular** doubly linked list.
Comments explain changes from the original code to this version.

Finally, an additional function is used here to prevent memory leaks.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node { // Using 'typedef' saves lots of typing (and reading
    int data;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev; // conventional layout of members
} node_t; // Notice '_t' as conventional suffix for user declared datatypes

node_t *print_nodes( node_t *head ) { // return pointer for use by caller
    if( head ) { // insurance against NULL pointer
        node_t *pn = head;

        printf( "Forward: " ); // exercise circular LL in both directions
        do {
            printf( "%d ", pn->data );
            pn = pn->next; // NB: 'next'
        } while( pn != head ); // circular, not linear! One full circuit
        puts( "" );

        printf( "Reverse: " );
        pn = pn->prev; // shift 'back' one node to begin
        do {
            printf( "%d ", pn->data );
            pn = pn->prev; // NB: 'prev'
        } while( pn != head->prev ); // circular, not linear! One full circuit
        puts( "" );
    }
    return head;
}

node_t *createList() { // Create "one ring to rule them all"
    int n = 0; // ALWAYS initialise variables
    do {
        printf( "Number of nodes (min 3): ");
        scanf( "%d", &n ); // 'while' protects against bad input
    } while( n < 3 );

    node_t *head = NULL;
    for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
        printf( "Enter the element of node %d: ", i + 1 );
        node_t *pn = (node_t *)calloc( 1, sizeof *pn ); // 'calloc()' zeros the block
        /* check 'pn == NULL' omitted for brevity */

        scanf("%d", &pn->data ); // read directly into destination (fewer variables)

        if( head == NULL )
            head = pn->prev = pn->next = pn; // 1st node, circular
        else {
            pn->prev = head->prev; // other nodes spliced-in ahead of 'head'
            pn->next = head;
            head->prev->next = pn;
            head->prev = pn;
        }
    }
    return head;
}

void freemem( node_t *head ) { // VERY important to respect "heap" storage!
    if( head == NULL ) return;

    node_t *pn = head; // traverse releasing nodes along the way
    do {
        node_t *pdel = pn;
        pn = pn->next;
        free( pdel );
    } while( pn != head );
}

int main() {
    // create, print, release, done...
    freemem( print_nodes( createList() ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Number of nodes (min 3): 5
Enter the element of node 1: 42
Enter the element of node 2: 56
Enter the element of node 3: 10
Enter the element of node 4: -5
Enter the element of node 5: 256
Forward: 42 56 10 -5 256
Reverse: 256 -5 10 56 42
```

This code implements and *proves* a **circular** doubly linked list. The example can be trivially adapted to a **linear** dbl-LL by severing the connection between `head` and `head->prev` after the ring has been formed, and then making necessary adjustments at other locations to account for the change.